# React Native: Rendered fewer hooks than expected

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I'm currently trying to develop an app with multiple screens. Specifically, I'm working on the navigator component that directs the user to the login screen or the home screen based on whether they are logged in or not.

To do this, I'm making use of hooks, React Navigation and Firebase. I have a state which tracks the user, and this state is updated using onAuthStateChanged() from Firebase, which is inside a useEffect hook.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {
    HomeScreen,
    LoginScreen,
    TimerScreen
} from '../screens';
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

const MainStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null); 

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, authUser => {
            if (authUser) {
                setUser(authUser);
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }
        });

        return subscriber;
    });

    const MainNavigator = () => (
        ...
    );

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            { user ? MainNavigator() : LoginScreen() }
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

AppNavigator is then called in my App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <AppNavigator />
    </View>
  );
}
```

However, whenever I run the app, I get

> Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

I've read a few posts with the same error message, and a common recommendation is to avoid having hooks inside conditional statements / loops. I did check that my useState and useEffect were at the top level of my component, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Right now I'm thinking that the problem could be arising because I'm navigating between screens, but I'll have to look more into it though.

Does anyone know what might be the issue, or any other possible fixes I could try? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```js
> user ? MainNavigator() : LoginScreen()
> ```

You are calling components as regular functions instead of creating elements from them. To create an element, use the JSX syntax, i.e.:

```
user ? <MainNavigator /> : <LoginScreen />
```

(Which will then be transpiled to `React.createElement`.)

The error occurs because when calling these components as functions, the code inside becomes a part of the render phase of the `AppNavigator` component. If, for example, `MainNavigator` contains hooks, and `LoginScreen` does not, then toggling between which function is (incorrectly) called also changes the number of hooks rendered, as suggested in the error message.